# ggplot2 2.0 new stat_ function: setting default scale for given aesthetics

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggproto

I try to use the new functionality of ggplot2 in R that allows creating our own `stat_` functions. I'm creating a simple one to compute and plot an interpolated surface between points arranged on a 2d array.

I would like to create a stat_topo() requiring `x`, `y`, and `val` aesthetics, plotting a simple `geom_raster` of interpolated `val` mapped to `fill`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(akima)

cpt_grp <- function(data, scales) {
  #interpolate data in 2D
  itrp <- akima::interp(data$x,data$y,data$val,linear=F,extrap=T)
  out <- expand.grid(x=itrp$x, y=itrp$y,KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = F)%>%
    mutate(fill=as.vector(itrp$z))
  # str(out)
  return(out)
}

StatTopo <- ggproto("StatTopo", Stat,
                    compute_group = cpt_grp,
                    required_aes = c("x","y","val")
)
stat_topo <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "raster",
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatTopo, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}

set.seed(1)
nchan <- 30
d <- data.frame(val = rnorm(nchan), # some random values to be mapped to fill color
         x = 1:nchan*cos(1:nchan), # the x and y position of the points to interpolate
         y = 1:nchan*sin(1:nchan))
plot(d$x,d$y)

ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y,val=val)) +
  stat_topo() +
  geom_point()
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error: numerical color values must be >= 0, found -1
```

I understand that this is because somehow the scale of the `fill` aesthetic is set to discrete.

If I enter this:

```
ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y,val=val)) +
  stat_topo() +
  scale_fill_continuous() +
  geom_point()
```

I get what I wanted: the expected raster with a continuous color scale, which I want the `stat_` to do ***by default...***

[image]

So I guess the question is: 
How can I prevent ggplot from setting a discrete scale here, and ideally set a default scale within the call to my new `stat_` function.

Comment: I kind of think you will need to have a paired `geom` to go with your stat to get what you want by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, when creating a new variable inside a `stat_` function, one needs to explicitly associate it to the aesthetic it will be mapped to with the parameter `default_aes = aes(fill = ..fill..)` within the ggproto definition.

This is telling ggplot that it is a calculated aesthetic and it will pick a scale based on the data type.

So here we need to define the `stat_` as follows:

```
cpt_grp <- function(data, scales) {
  # interpolate data in 2D
  itrp <- akima::interp(data$x,data$y,data$val,linear=F,extrap=T)
  out <- expand.grid(x=itrp$x, y=itrp$y,KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = F)%>%
    mutate(fill=as.vector(itrp$z))
  # str(out)
  return(out)
}

StatTopo <- ggproto("StatTopo", Stat,
                    compute_group = cpt_grp,
                    required_aes = c("x","y","val"),
                    default_aes = aes(fill = ..fill..)
)

stat_topo <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "raster",
                      position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                      inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatTopo, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)    
  )
}
```

Then the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
nchan <- 30
d <- data.frame(val = rnorm(nchan),
                x = 1:nchan*cos(1:nchan),
                y = 1:nchan*sin(1:nchan))
ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y,val=val)) +
  stat_topo() +
  geom_point()
```

Produces as expected:

[image: The result of stat_topo]

Without the need to specify a `scale_` manually, but leaving the possibility to adapt the scale easily as usual with e.g. `scale_fill_gradient2(low = 'blue',mid='white',high='red')`

I got this answer here: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1481

Answer (score 1):

Okay, slept on it, and had an idea, and I think this might do what you want. In your `stat_topo` layer function instead of the `ggproto` I returned a list with it as the first element and then added to that list another `ggproto` with a call to `scale_fill_continuous()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(akima)

cpt_grp <- function(data, scales) {
  #interpolate data in 2D
  itrp <- akima::interp(data$x,data$y,data$val,linear=F,extrap=T)
  out <- expand.grid(x=itrp$x, y=itrp$y,KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = F)%>%
    mutate(fill=as.vector(itrp$z))
  return(out)
}
StatTopo <- ggproto("StatTopo", Stat,
                    compute_group = cpt_grp,
                    required_aes = c("x","y","val")
)
stat_topo <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "raster",
                      position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                      inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  list(
    layer(
      stat = StatTopo, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
      position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
      params = list(na.rm = na.rm )
    ),
    scale_fill_continuous()
  )
}
set.seed(1)
nchan <- 30
d <- data.frame(val = rnorm(nchan), # some random values to be mapped to fill color
                x = 1:nchan*cos(1:nchan), # the x and y position of interp points
                y = 1:nchan*sin(1:nchan))
 ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y,val=val)) +
   stat_topo() +
   geom_point()
```

yielding the same picture as above.

Comment: great, thanks! key was creating the list in the stat_topo. I tried to add them earlier but it didn't want to.

Comment: Still it seems there's something fishy in the way the values are mapped to the `fill` aesthetic here. I filed an issue on ggplot github.